# Is there an API based method to get products data from Clickbank network?

Tags: php, api, clickbank

Is there an API based method to get products data from Clickbank network?
I need search products through keywords.

From [Clickbank site](http://www.clickbank.com/help/account-help/account-tools/clickbank-api/):

> Supported APIs
>
> For version 1.2, the following API’s will be supported:
>
> Orders API: https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/orders The Orders API
>   allows you to get order information by receipt or date/time
>   parameters.
>
> Shipping API: https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/shipping The Shipping
>   API allows you to get shipping information for one or many physical
>   good orders by receipt or date/time parameters.
>
> Tickets API: https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/tickets The Ticket API
>   allows you to update an order’s status to returned or canceled thru
>   the creation of a transaction ticket. Additionally, you may search for
>   existing tickets by user.
>
> Sandbox API: https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox The
>   Sandbox API provides an environment to create test accounts, developer
>   keys, and orders. Once established, it can be used to test the tickets
>   and order API’s.
>
> Upsell API: https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/upsells The Upsell API
>   allows qualified users to create upsells via the API.
>
> Ship Notice API:
>   https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/shipping/shipnotice The Ship Notice
>   API is a child of the shipping API and allows for ship notice
>   generation.
>
> Sandbox Product Creation API:
>   https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox/product The Sandbox
>   Product Creation API is a child of the sandbox API and allows users to
>   create products in the sandbox environment.
>
> Quickstats API: https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/quickstats The
>   Quickstats API provides stats about the user’s account.

None of these APIs seems works over the general marketplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clickbank Marketplace is given to you as an XML Feed: http://www.clickbank.com/help/account-help/account-tools/marketplace-feed/

Comment: This is the "BEST" answer you will get, http://www.clickbank.com/feeds/marketplace_feed_v2.xml.zip  Here's the Feed it's self.  THe site uses a "DATAFEED" Vs API for the products.

Comment: I know about the `XML feed`. What I need is search by keywords. thanks.-

Comment: You have to import the XML feed and do searches to it it's self.  OR scrape data from the search feature.  Those are the only options.

Comment: Yes, scraping is the only way at the moment.